# Enabling microsoft accessibility for Flex Window hangs application after clicking on identified object

Tags: silktest

After enabling accessibility for a flex window object, I fired an object.click which brought up a dialog-box. After closing the dialog box, the application went to hung state. So I found the coordinates of object using getrect , restarted both application and silk, kept accessibility disabled clicked on the mainwindow using the coordinates and the problem did not recur. The problem even when I retrieved the coordinates with accessibility and manually clicked on the icon.

I am even unable to fetch locator hierarchy with accessibility enabled when I try to retrieve for objects that are visible only through enabled accessibility. Nothing is captured (blank recorder hierarchy) and the recording stops working any further. I guess the agent goes into some kind of loop or excepts out. Kindly advise.

Comment: Why do you need to enable accessibility? Silk Test has full support for Flex - doesn't that get you what you need?

Comment: No - not all objects are exposed - enabling accessibility exposes some more objects

Comment: Which version of Flex? Please check the system requirements. Perhaps you have to use an older version of Silk.

Comment: Yes we are using 13.5 with no company desire to upgrade :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a product issue and got this fixed - not an issue on SilkTest side